# How to get the size of the table in Amazon Athena in AWS Lambda?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to find the size of the table in an Amazon S3 bucket by using Amazon Athena (leveraging lambda). Is there any query for that or code?

I have tried the following method but not working in Athena as it's saying not supported by Athena.

```
SHOW TBLPROPERTIES table_name;``
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to find out the Table size other than querying whole table which is an expensive operation. To find out size of the table you can simply find out the S3 location(something like [this](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/athena/get-table-metadata.html)) to which table pointed to and use lambda/any sdk to do something similar to following:

```
total_size = 0
bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('athenabucket')
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
  total_size += obj.size
  print(obj.size)
print(total_size)
```